# Is there a simple JavaScript slider?

Tags: javascript, slider, controls, wmp

I need to create a custom volume slider for a WMP object.  The current slider is complicated to modify, and use, is there a simple way to generate a slider on an HTML page that can have it's value passed to a javascript function?

Comment: With HTML5, native sliders can be declared and CSS-styled. `<input type="range">` Try it!

Comment: But unfortunately doesn't work in Firefox yet :(

Comment: **HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904852/html-scroll-box-with-horizontal-controls-for-vertical-scrolling/

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14095880/1163000

Comment: @TaufikNurrohman You've got that backwards actually, this question was posted 4 years before the one you linked.  The new one should likewise be closed.

Comment: Shield UI's Slider widget is what you need: http://demos.shieldui.com/web/slider/basic-usage

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) ([API docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider))

Comment: Doesn't work so nicely on mobile without the additional libraries of [jquery-touch-punch](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch). And this also conflicts with `$.fn.button` from Twitter Bootstrap, so watch out.

Answer (score 35):

hey i've just created my own JS slider because I had enough of the heavy Jquery UI one.  Interested to hear people's thoughts.  Been on it for 5 hours, so really really early stages.

[jsfiddle_slider](http://jsfiddle.net/LucP/BPdKR/2/)

Comment: Nice example - I'm looking for a control to fade the opacity of one image over another, so might try this.

Comment: Thanks for the example -- a lack of simple slider controls that are not part of some much larger library has been really annoying. This motivated me to try to just go write my own that meets my needs

Comment: For those of you wondering: WinXP/IE7 works great, WinXP/IE6 works but needs CSS tweaking, iOS5/Safari does not work (guess other touch devices won't either). For such a small piece of code it is very impressive, Great work Luc! thanks!

Comment: Can you make it vertical too?

Answer (score 20):

[HTML 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/) with [Webforms 2](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-forms/current-work/) provides an `<input type="range">` which will make the browser generate a native slider for you. Unfortunately all browsers doesn't have support for this, however [google](http://code.google.com/p/webforms2/) has implemented all Webforms 2 controls with js. IIRC the js is intelligent enough to know if the browser has implemented the control, and triggers only if there is no native implementation.

From my point of view it should be considered best practice to use the browsers native controls when possible.

Answer (score 20):

A simple slider: I have just tested this in **pure HTML5**, and **it's so simple** !

```
<input type="range">
```

It works like a charm on Chrome. I've not tested other browsers yet.

Comment: could you clarify a little more?

Comment: I think you should write `<input type="range">` inside an html file, and browse this file in a browser that accepts HTML5. You would see a simple slider.

Comment: okay! I got the point.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another light [JavaScript Slider](http://blog.ovidiu.ch/javascript-slider) that seems to fit your needs.

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score 5):

[Yahoo UI library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) has also a [slider control](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/slider/slider-ticks.html)...

Answer (score 4):

script.aculo.us has a [slider control](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/slider) that might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice javascript slider, it's very easy to implement. You can download the zip package here: http://ruwix.com/javascript-volume-slider-control/

p.s. here the simplified version of the above script:

[image]

[**DEMO link**](http://codepen.io/tazotodua/debug/wnDjq)

Answer (score 2):

The lightweight MooTools framework has one: http://demos.mootools.net/Slider

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Slider from Filament Group, It has very good user experience

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple slider object for easy to use

[pagecolumn_webparts_sliders](http://www.pagecolumn.com/webparts/sliders.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The Carpe Slider has newer versions also: 
v1.5 [carpe_ambiprospect_slider](http://carpe.ambiprospect.com/slider/)
v2.0b ...slider/drafts/v2.0/

Answer (score -1):

The code below should be enough to get you started. Tested in Opera, IE and Chrome.

```
<script>
var l=0;
function f(i){
im = 'i' + l;
d=document.all[im];
d.height=99;
document.all.f1.t1.value=i;
im = 'i' + i;
d=document.all[im];
d.height=1;
l=i;
}
</script>
<center>
<form id='f1'>
<input type=text value=0 id='t1'>
</form>
<script>
for (i=0;i<=50;i++)
 {
 s = "<img src='j.jpg' height=99 width=9 onMouseOver='f(" + i + ")' id='i" + i + "'>";
 document.write(s);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Inline events, `document.write`, the `<center>` element - it's like 1999 all over again!