# Google chrome vertical <input type="range" />

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

On opera, i can do the following

```
<style>
#range{
 width: 20px;
 heigth: 300px;
}
</style>

<input type="range" id="range" />
```

and it will render a vertical slider. However, this doesn't seem to work on chrome. Is there a way I can do this? (I'm not looking for any jQuery sliders or anything)

Comment: So with my Chrome Version "9.0.597.98" I get a slider: [Click](http://diveintohtml5.org/examples/input-type-range.html). Maybe you have to specify anymore attributes?

Comment: @Vuurwerk he is asking for a *vertical* slider.

Comment: Oh, ok sry, didn't notice that. This seems not, yet, to work with Chrome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It seems Chromium does not yet implement support for this yet:**

See: http://www.chromium.org/developers/web-platform-status/forms

> ## Not available yet
>
> - Localization of
> - Dedicated UIs for color, date, datetime, datetime-local, month, time,
>     and week types
> - **Automatic switching to vertical range**
> - Value sanitization algorithms
> - datalist element, list attribute, and list/selectedOption properties

**Edit:** [Vuurwerk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309882/vuurwerk) [indicated](http://swatelier.info/at/forms/range.asp) that it is actually possible to alter the presentation using the `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical` property. Although this *does* transform it into a   vertical slider, I would not recommend doing this, since it will break your layout and doesn't look really pretty: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/SPjsf/15/).

If you *really* want a vertical slider, use a [JavaScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173046/is-there-a-simple-javascript-slider). Support for `<input type="range" />` is very basic at the moment anyway, so you are probably better off with a graceful degradation or progressive enhancement approach.

Comment: I found a solution using `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;`. Found here: http://swatelier.info/at/forms/range.asp (scroll down to the last paragraph)

Comment: -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; works in modern chrome browser.

Answer (score 8):

-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;

Answer (score 5):

Maybe with a css transform ?

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90);
```

Another solution could be to use the slider module from jQuery UI.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical

Comment: As long as you're clever about your `transform-origin`, this works.

Answer (score 3):

```
input[type='range']{        
    width:20px;
    height:140px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */        
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 0; 
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to work correctly in IE10 on Windows 8 or the default Android Browser on v4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

**As Aron has said there is no support for webkit browser.**

However this is what i could do for achieving the output.

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.opacitySlider {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 125px;
  height: 20px;
}
.opacitySlider:before {
  content: " ";
  left: 10px;
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 9px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid transparent;
  border-left: 115px solid #ccc;
}
.opacitySlider input[type=range] {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 125px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.opacitySlider input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #69a80e;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.opacitySlider input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.opacitySlider input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #69a80e;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.opacitySlider input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower, .opacitySlider input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
}
.opacitySlider input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  height: 18px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
}
.opacitySlider input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  background: #69a80e;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="opacitySlider">
  <input step="any" type="range">
</div>
```