# Ruby on Rails vertical slider

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I want a vertical slider on my site, I am using ruby 4.0 and I can use

```
<%= f.range_field :value, :min => 0, :max => 250 %>
```

to display what I want, but I want this bar to be vertical and not horizontal (default?), anyways I tried, of course to google the answer but didn't find a clue about how to achieve this, I went to API documentation at [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-range_field) and all I found was "Accepts same options as range_field_tag" but then I didn't find range_field_tag anywhere, I wonder if I will have to implement a third party solution to this... if so, do you recommend any gem or jquery like library?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing this and that's why rails does not provide any option for it. You will have to dig into some css to achieve it.

Here is a related SO question [Google chrome vertical <input type="range" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001464/google-chrome-vertical-input-type-range)

Comment: oh, that's a pitty, I wonder if they will come up with something to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `custom_id` with the id generated for the range field
and in your css add the below code

```
#custom_id {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}
```

For eg: Assuming that `value` is your field name, then id generated would be `modelname_value`

Comment: Close enough, but this works only for chrome, similar code for mozilla doesn't work, neither for IE, will keep looking for an answer, thanks though :D