# Simple pure Javascript drag controller slider

Tags: javascript, slider, onmousedown, onmousemove

Hi Developers all over the world.

I would like to have some help with a simple, pure Javascript *(30 lines)*, JQuery free *(and other library's)* **drag control slider.**

I have been searching months and found many scripts but i don't like -Jquery cause most script need 4, 5, 6 javascript includes..  I prefer smaller and basic script..  i like to ajust them like i want and i also can lean alot from smaller scripts.

All i need is a simple slider that i can use for:  rescale images, scroll page, change brightness on images *(with PHP)* etc.

I am new with javascript *(2 months)*, this is how far i get now.. Sorry for the bad variable names...

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      _item = null;
      mouse_x = 0;
      drag_x = 0; 
      function move_init() {
        document.onmousemove = _move;
        document.onmouseup = _stop;
      }
      function _stop(){
         _item = null;
      }
      function _move(e){
        mouse_x = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
        if(_item != null){
             _item.style.left = (mouse_x - drag_x) + "px";
        }
      }
      function _move_item(drag)
      {
        _item = drag;
        drag_x = mouse_x - _item.offsetLeft;
      }
move_init();
drag.onmousedown=_move_item();   // Agh.. did'nt figure out how this works
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#drag{background:#797979;color:#fff;width:30px;height:15px;position:relative;}
#track{background:red; width:200px;}
</style>

<div id="track"><div id="drag" onmousedown="_move_item(this);" >x</div></div>
```

i appriciate your help.

I wrote this on 31 december 2012.. So happy new year. Please be good for each other.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @user1938684, if you're looking for a code review, please post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Otherwise, if you have a specific question or problem with this code, feel free to state exactly what that is. As it stands, it's not clear exactly what kind of help you need.

Comment: I'll be happy if someone have a pice of code for me.. My code is not pasted for review...   more for verify what i'm searching for.

please give me a code.. then i'm happy and continue my development.

Comment: Out of curiosity did you find a code? I'm looking for the same, still without result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple JavaScript slider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173046/is-there-a-simple-javascript-slider)

Comment: For new developers stumbling on this, use an input type range, let the browser do the work for you: `<input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10">`
Preview: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This code works in modern browsers. Just create some polyfill for that `addEventListener` and this custom range slider will be safe to use:

```
function rangeSlider(id, onDrag) {

    var range = document.getElementById(id),
        dragger = range.children[0],
        draggerWidth = 10, // width of your dragger
        down = false,
        rangeWidth, rangeLeft;

    dragger.style.width = draggerWidth + 'px';
    dragger.style.left = -draggerWidth + 'px';
    dragger.style.marginLeft = (draggerWidth / 2) + 'px';

    range.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        rangeWidth = this.offsetWidth;
        rangeLeft = this.offsetLeft;
        down = true;
        updateDragger(e);
        return false;
    });

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        updateDragger(e);
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        down = false;
    });

    function updateDragger(e) {
        if (down && e.pageX >= rangeLeft && e.pageX <= (rangeLeft + rangeWidth)) {
            dragger.style.left = e.pageX - rangeLeft - draggerWidth + 'px';
            if (typeof onDrag == "function") onDrag(Math.round(((e.pageX - rangeLeft) / rangeWidth) * 100));
        }
    }

}
```

### Example Usage

```
<style>
.range-slider {
  width:300px;
  height:20px;
  margin:0 auto 1em;
  position:relative;
  cursor:e-resize;
}
.range-slider:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:9px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  background-color:black;
}
.range-slider span {
  display:block;
  height:inherit;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  background-color:red;
  cursor:inherit;
}
</style>

<div class="range-slider" id="range-slider-1">
  <span></span>
</div>

<script>
rangeSlider('range-slider-1', function(value) {
    document.getElementById('test-area').innerHTML = value + '%';
});
</script>
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/dulifezi/2/edit

---

#### Update

I’m creating a repo for this snippet here → https://github.com/taufik-nurrohman/range-slider

Comment: Dragging doesn't seem to work on touch devices. Tested on an Android tablet.

Comment: @redburn The **GitHub** repo version has support for touch events.

Comment: @TaufikNurrohman any idea how to move this code to typescript (angular)?

Comment: @karlo1zg Not an angular guy, sorry. No idea.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at DragDealer.js:
https://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/

There's an example of changing opacity of an image based on the value of a slider here.

Hope this helps!